# SQL Server count between before and after midnight - 24 hours

Tags: sql-server, datetime, between

I need to count records between before midnight and after midnight with a field that uses 24 hour datetime. The following statement has worked perfectly for times that are in the same day, e.g. between 10:30 am and 4:29 pm:

```
WHERE CAST (theader_tdatetime AS time) BETWEEN '10:30' and '16:29'
```

However, I need to also select records from 7:31 pm to 2:00 am, and my statement no longer works:

```
WHERE CAST (theader_tdatetime AS time) BETWEEN '19:31' and '02:00'
```

How can I select records from this timeframe?

Edit: A few sample records that bridge the midnight gap

```
2015-11-20 23:48:52.000  
2015-11-20 23:49:58.000  
2015-11-20 23:51:35.000  
2015-11-20 23:58:51.000  
2015-11-20 23:59:26.000  
2015-11-21 00:04:03.000  
2015-11-21 00:04:36.000  
2015-11-21 00:05:11.000
```

Comment: please show some sample records

Comment: 0:2:00 is the next day

Comment: What is the data type of this column?

Comment: you can assume if you use 13:00 (IF YOUR START BETWEEN) or above SQL understands you mean 24 hour time, but if its below and your START , it does NOT assume.  Hence be explicit with AM / PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE CAST (transaction_date AS time)
BETWEEN '15:30 PM' and '23:59 PM' 
or CAST (transaction_date AS time) BETWEEN '0:00 AM' and '02:00 AM'
```

Comment: This works well, and I was unaware of the AM/PM functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE CAST (theader_tdatetime AS time) >= '19:31' OR CAST (theader_tdatetime AS time) <= '02:00'